# Getting input from a content editable div in react

Tags: html, reactjs, contenteditable, react-dom

Change handler

```
const contentref=useRef()
const handleclick=()=>{
   setContent(contentref.current.value)
   console.log(contentref.current.value)
}
```

Tag

```
<div
    name="textbox"  
    ref ={contentref}  
    className="textbox" 
    onChange={e=>handleclick()} 
    contentEditable="true" 
    role="textbox" 
    aria-multiline="true" 
    tabIndex="0px" 
    placeholder="Type something..."  
    spellCheck="false">
</div>
```

I have been trying to get the input from the content editable div but it is not returning anything.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] like code sandbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const handleclick = () => {
    setConntent(contentref.current.innerHTML)
}
```

use ref.cuurent.innerHTML .